# Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) will not install any Linux Distro

Tags: installation, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using a Windows PC with the following specs:

- Edition: Windows 11 Home
- Version: 23H2
- OS build: 22631.2338
- Experience: Windows Feature Experience Pack 100.22674.1000.0
- Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-9400F CPU @ 2.90GHz 2.90 GHz
- Installed RAM: 16.0 GB
- System type: 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor

I have been unable to successfully install any Linux distribution, either via the Microsoft Store or from command prompt. On command prompt (run as admin), the command wsl `--install -d <distro>` returns the error code "0x80070005". Same for Microsoft Store.

PowerShell (run as admin) doesn't even recognise `wsl` as a command, returning:

> wsl : The term 'wsl' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
> function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
> name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
> try again. At line:1 char:1 wsl   CategoryInfo          :
> ObjectNotFound: (wsl:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
> FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

I managed to successfully install Ubuntu by downloading the .AppxBundle file (link from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual, specific link https://aka.ms/wslubuntu) but when I try to run it I get the error message:

> Windows cannot access the specified device, path or file. you may not
> have the appropriate permissions to access the item".

I have tried updating the permissions of the root folder ("C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu_2204.1.7.0_x64__79rhkp1fndgsc") to no avail.

I have ensured that the "Windows Subsystem for Linux" and "Virtual Machine Platform" Windows Features are enabled and made sure that the WSL version is set to '2' with the command `wsl --set-default-version 2` in admin command prompt.

I even went into the BIOS settings of my PC ensured that my Intel CPU has the setting for allowing 'virtualisation' enabled.

I'm open to any suggestions.

Comment: Did you customize your Windows installation in any way, for example in an attempt to disable telemetry or removing built-in apps or whatever? Or maybe altering ACLs on critical system folders to gain access?

Comment: You should never, ever, never take ownership of the folder `WindowsApps`. Maybe [this tool](https://github.com/AgentRev/WindowsAppsUnfukker) will undo the damage.

Comment: Windows 11 23H2 hasn’t been released yet, please edit your question, to indicate what version of Windows 11 you actually are running. The fact you are installing optional Windows features means you’re not installing the current version of WSL from the Windows Store.  You should do that considering your having problems running WSL

Comment: @Ramhound I don't know what to tell you, that's what my Windows system tells me my version is. I'm on the Windows Insider Programme Beta Channel, which I believe would explain why I have the version early.

Comment: @harrymc noted, thanks for the tip. I'll check that tool out. I should clarify, all the problems I've described happened before I messed with ownership of WindowsApps

Comment: @DanielB not as far as I know... unless opting into the Windows Insider Programme (Beta Channel) counts as customisation

Comment: @harrymc EDIT: I used the tool and it seems to have worked. Thanks again!

Comment: @WillJ1312 - Having a Windows Insider Preview build is relevant information. You still need to be installing WSL from the command, which by default, installs from the Windows Store. WSL recently received a significant update but only the version on the Windows Store is update.

Answer (score 0):

You should never, ever, never take ownership of the folder WindowsApps.

If you did take ownership, this tool might help to undo the damage:
[WindowsAppsUnfukker](https://github.com/AgentRev/WindowsAppsUnfukker).
(I find the name quite appropriate.)